# Проблема с кодировкой при запуске на командной строке

Tags: java, spring, curl, java-ee, spring-boot

Всем привет я хочу хочу запустить cURL команду

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"time\": \"2019-12-27T09:50:02.000+0000\", \"unread\": true, \"message\": \"asd\", \"from\": \"Vadim\"}" localhost:8080/api/save
```

При запуске он все правильно возвращает, только за место сообщения какие-то непонятные символы,

```
{"message":"╨б╨╛╨╛╨▒╤Й╨╡╨╜╨╕╨╡ ╤Г╤Б╨┐╨╡╤И╨╜╨╛ ╤Б╨╛╤Е╤А╨░╨╜╨╡╨╜╨╛"}
```

как можно исправить так, чтобы в ответе нормально на русском было написано

```
{"message":"Сообщение сохранено"}
```

Вот мой код

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {
    private final MessageRepository repository;
    private final PageRequest lastRequest;

    private List<Long> chekedMessages = new ArrayList<>();


    @Autowired
    public MessageServiceImpl(MessageRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
        lastRequest = new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");
    }

    @Override
    public MessageStatus add(@RequestBody  Message message) {
        if(message == null) {
            System.out.println("Пришел пустой запрос на сохранение данных");

        }
        MessageStatus status = new MessageStatus();
        try {
            repository.save(message);
            status.setMessage("Сообщение успешно сохранено");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            status.setMessage("Во время сохранения сообщения произошла ошибка");
        }
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: Всё правильно. Сервер возвращает данные в кодировке utf-8, curl выводит в консоль ровно то, что принял, а консоль у вас, видимо - cmd, работающая с кодировкой cp866.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее проблема с кодировкой в Вашем консоле, а не сервер возвращает непонятные символы. Проверьте кодировку командной строки и поменяйте её на UTF-8.